# How can I reproduce this error: The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator

Tags: list-view-threshold

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have a list view threshold with 5000 items on the production environment. I exceeded this limit and got this error:

The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator

How can I reproduce this error on my development environment? I would like to change some custom code to bypass this error.

Comment: How many items do you have in development environment?

Comment: Just save the list as a template, include the content and download it. Restore to your dev environment and do your testing.

Comment: I have 5025 items in my list on development environment. I created some tool which copies a bulk items to this list. Still have no error. Maybe the permissions. I am farm account on dev. On production not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to reproduce the error on your development environment you need log in as a normal user to your dev farm. Administrators default list view threshold is 20,000 items and 5,000 for normal user, thus rendering the error. However, the threshold is there for one reason, so i would not recommend to override it in your production environment.

> By default, the list view threshold prevents operations that will involve more than 5,000 items, such as queries that will return more than 5,000 items or adding a column to a list that contains more than 5,000 items. Although this is a configurable default, we strongly recommend that you keep it. If poorly performing queries are used on lists with more than 5,000 items, overall throughput can significantly decrease when you increase this limit.
>
> The list view threshold is the maximum number of list or library items that a database operation, such as a query, can involve at one time. By default, this is set to 5,000 items. This limit has a major effect on large lists because, by the definition of this threshold, a large list is a list that has more items than this limit. Operations that exceed this limit are throttled

[Designing large lists and maximizing list performance (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx)

Comment: thanks, so thats the reason I cannot reproduce this error on dev. I will try it with a normal user.

Comment: Yes, as you were accessing your list as a admin/superuser. It's better to filter out big list for best performance and avoid the error message.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the error?

Comment: not yet on dev environment. I did request another account to test it with lower permissions.

Comment: Tell me if you need any additional help later on. :)

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is the one of the solution for this problem.

Link : https://www.portalfronthosting.com/blog/whats-up-with-sharepoint-list-message-the-attempted-operation-is-prohibited-because-it-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-enforced-by-the-administrator

Comment: indexing  column in SharePoint list(Data:300000) after Display Error "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator" .

Comment: Pass this caml query:----<View><Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-02-28T18:30:00Z</Value></Geq><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2017-03-01T18:29:00Z</Value></Leq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='EmployeeID'  LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>7</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Deleted1' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where></Query><RowLimit>4999</RowLimit></View>